# Adding custom Text changes the horizontal alignment in Content type

Tags: 7

I have a content type. For two fields I am using horizontal tab item . those two fields Section_grid_image and section_grid_image_path are displayed one after another so I have used hook_form_alter and added custom CSS.

```
function displayor_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

//Load CSS 
$form['#attached']['css'][drupal_get_path('module', 'displayor') . '/form.css'] = array();


if ($form['#id'] == 'section-node-form'){ //contenttype-node-form

   $form['field_section_grid_image']['#prefix'] = '<div id="leftcolumn">';
   $form['field_section_grid_image']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
   //where field_test is your file upload field


   $form['field_section_grid_image_path']['#prefix'] = '<div id="rightcolumn"> OR';
   $form['field_section_grid_image_path']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
   //where field_test is your file upload field
 }
}
```

CSS

```
#leftcolumn{
width: 400px;  
float: left;
}

#rightcolumn{
 width: 600px;
 margin-left: 200px;
}

#innercolumn{
 width: 500px;
}
```

My alignment is getting like this:
[image]

I want the fields and OR to be displayed in a line.

How to do this.

**EDIT: Got the answer.Below CSS did the trick.**

```
function displayor_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

//Load CSS 
$form['#attached']['css'][drupal_get_path('module', 'displayor') . '/form.css'] = array();


if ($form['#id'] == 'section-node-form'){ //contenttype-node-form

   $form['field_section_grid_image']['#prefix'] = '<div id="leftcolumn">';
   $form['field_section_grid_image']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
   //where field_test is your file upload field


   $form['field_section_grid_image_path']['#prefix'] = '<div id="rightcolumn"><span class="or">(OR)</span>';
   $form['field_section_grid_image_path']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
   //where field_test is your file upload field
 }
}
```

CSS

```
#leftcolumn, 
#rightcolumn,
#orseperator
 {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 77px;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 .or
  { left: 382px;
   margin-right: 25px;
   margin-top: 1px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 76px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just do the following:

```
   $form['field_section_grid_image']['#suffix'] = '</div><div> OR';

   $form['field_section_grid_image_path']['#prefix'] = '</div><div id="rightcolumn">';
```

Comment: hm its not working. Alignment is not in the same line.

Comment: Your going to probably have to float those divs if you havent or set them to inline.

Comment: Float the divs. Also tried displaying inline. Its not working

Comment: Whats your output if its not the following? <div id="leftcolumn"></div><div>OR</div><div id="rightcolumn"></div>

Comment: Same alignment as in the image of the question.

Comment: But when you inspect the code are you getting similar to the following? <div id="leftcolumn"></div><div>OR</div><div id="rightcolumn"></div>

Comment: Yes When inspecting getting the same.

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/s3gcM/, thats what your aiming for.

Comment: The link is useful. But for me I have to add span. Edited my question. Adding Span and writing some css for the span class did the trick.